# 12 column Bootstrap. Responsive website max width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, width

The wordpress theme uses 12 column Bootstrap framework and is responsive. It is too wide for me. I am not sure whether it is possible or not to do so, but I have one idea.

The width of the theme is set to be 1230px. When you are slowly making the browser smaller - responsiveness kicks in and makes it 1000px wide, which is a perfect width for me. I would like to fix the width to always be 1000px.

Could you please give me any ideas on how to go around doing that?

No idea whether it is possible or not, but maybe there's a way to restrict website's width to 1000px by "pretending" that browser is not big enough to display full 1230px.

Sorry if it's confusing.

Thanks.

JD.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question abit confusing but hope this helps. This is the CSS which you need to use in your stylsheets to modify the default container for different screen sizes

```
@media(max-width:767px){
    .container{
        /* Width for the Container */
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px){
    .container{
        /* Width for the Container */
    }
}

@media(min-width:992px){
    .container{
        /* Width for the Container */
    }
}

@media(min-width:1200px){
    .container{
        /* Width for the Container */
    }
}
```